# Unable to delete zones in the effective configuration

Tags: switch, brocade, san

I was given the task of zoning and mistakenly I created new cfg and did zoning of a host. Now I am trying to delete zoning using below steps:
Zonedelete
Cfgsave cfgenable
Cfgremove
Cfgsave cfgenable

But zones are not getting removed from effective configuration.
I searched through Google and it said cfgdisable and cfgdelete which I can not as it will disable all the zoning configuration. Please help me to resolve this.

Previous switch configuration:

```
login as: bhmin
bhmin@192.68.151.62's password:
swd77:FID128:bhmin> cfgshow
Defined configuration:
 cfg:   Primera_FabricA
                Primera_ZoneA_huhh_101; Primera_ZoneA_SAP_NProd;
                Primera_ZoneA_SAPProd; phzprim_20310002ac02ffbh_00;
                phzprim_20220002ac02ffbh_00; phzprim_23450002ac02ffbh_00;
                phzprim_23450002ac02ffbh_00; 
 cfg:   tdz___cfg___auto
                phzprim_20220002ac02ffbh_00; phzprim_20220002ac02ffbh_00;
                phzprim_20220002ac02ffbh_00; phzprim_200380112ac02ffbh_00;
                phzprim_2230002ac02ffbh_00; phzprim_2230002ac02ffbh_00;
                phzprim_2230002ac02ffbh_00; phzprim_2230002ac02ffbh_00;
                tdz___zone___auto
 zone:  Primera_N0S3P1_Synergy_IQ6C5_1_
                Primera_N0S3P1; Synergy_IQ6C5_1_
 zone:  Primera_N0S3P3_Synergy_IQ6C5_2_
                Primera_N0S3P3; Synergy_IQ6C5_2_
 zone:  Primera_N1S3P1_Synergy_IQ6C5_3_
                Primera_N1S3P1; Synergy_IQ6C5_3_
 zone:  Primera_N1S3P3_Synergy_IQ6C5_4_
                Primera_N1S3P3; Synergy_IQ6C5_4_
 zone:  Primera_N2S3P1_Synergy_IQ7C5_1_
                Primera_N2S3P1; Synergy_IQ7C5_1_
 zone:  Primera_N2S3P3_Synergy_IQ7C5_2_
                Primera_N2S3P3; Synergy_IQ7C5_2_
 zone:  Primera_N3S3P1_Synergy_IQ7C5_3_
                Primera_N3S3P1; Synergy_IQ7C5_3_
 zone:  Primera_N3S3P3_Synergy_IQ7C5_4_
                Primera_N3S3P3; Synergy_IQ7C5_4_
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_huhh_101
                f1_b10_101; f1_b11_101; f1_i2_huhh; f1_b3_huhh; f1_b4_huhh;
                f1_b5_huhh; f1_b7_101; f1_b8_101; f1_b9_101; fi_b1_huhh;
                Primera_N0S3P1; Primera_N0S3P3; Primera_N1S3P1;
                Primera_N1S3P3
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_SAPProd
                f2_b1_sapprd; f2_i2_sapprd; f2_b3_sapprd; Primera_N2S3P1;
                Primera_N2S3P3; Primera_N3S3P1; Primera_N3S3P3
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_SAP_NProd
                f2_b10_sapnprd; f2_b7_sapnprd; f2_b8_sapnprd; f2_b9_sapnprd;
                Primera_N2S3P1; Primera_N2S3P3; Primera_N3S3P1;
                Primera_N3S3P3
 zone:  ZONEA-MIGRATION
                C7000AP1; C7000AP2; C7000BP1; C7000BP2;
                f1_b5_huhh; f1_b9_101
 zone:  phzprim_20310002ac02ffbh_00
                20:21:00:02:ac:00:ff:bh; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:18;
                10:77:i2:66:g9:c0:00:1d; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:20
 zone:  phzprim_20330002ac02ffbh_00
                20:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:18;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:20
 zone:  phzprim_21310002ac02ffbh_00
                21:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:18;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:20
 zone:  phzprim_21330002ac02ffbh_00
                21:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:18;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:20
 zone:  phzprim_22310002ac02ffbh_00
                22:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:c2:89:g9:c0:19:20;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:8c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
 zone:  phzprim_22330002ac02ffbh_00
                22:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:24;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:4c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
 zone:  phzprim_23310002ac02ffbh_00
                23:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:24;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:4c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
 zone:  phzprim_23330002ac02ffbh_00
                23:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:24;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:4c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58; 10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c;
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
 zone:  tdz___zone___auto
                00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01
 alias: C7000AP1
                20:13:00:11:0a:00:42:65
 alias: C7000AP2
                20:13:00:11:0a:00:9d:c4
 alias: C7000BP1
                20:14:00:11:0a:00:42:65
 alias: C7000BP2
                20:14:00:11:0a:00:9d:c4
 alias: Primera_N0S3P1
                20:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N0S3P3
                20:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N1S3P1
                21:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N1S3P3
                21:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N2S3P1
                22:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N2S3P3
                22:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N3S3P1
                23:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Primera_N3S3P3
                23:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 alias: Synergy_IQ6C5_1_
                20:08:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ6C5_2_
                20:0a:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ6C5_3_
                20:09:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ6C5_4_
                20:0b:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ7C5_1_
                20:0c:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ7C5_2_
                20:0d:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ7C5_3_
                20:0e:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: Synergy_IQ7C5_4_
                20:0f:00:11:0a:07:17:k9
 alias: f1_b10_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:68
 alias: f1_b11_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
 alias: f1_i2_huhh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
 alias: f1_b3_huhh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20
 alias: f1_b4_huhh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:24
 alias: f1_b5_huhh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28
 alias: f1_b7_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c
 alias: f1_b8_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:60
 alias: f1_b9_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:64
 alias: f2_b10_sapnprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58
 alias: f2_b1_sapprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:40
 alias: f2_i2_sapprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:44
 alias: f2_b3_sapprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:48
 alias: f2_b7_sapnprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:4c
 alias: f2_b8_sapnprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50
 alias: f2_b9_sapnprd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54
 alias: fi_b1_huhh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18

Effective configuration:
 cfg:   Primera_Synergy_FabricA
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_huhh_101
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:68
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:6c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:24
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:5c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:60
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:64
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18
                20:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                21:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                21:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_SAPProd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:40
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:44
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:48
                22:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                22:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                23:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                23:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 zone:  Primera_ZoneA_SAP_NProd
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:58
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:4c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:50
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:54
                22:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                22:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                23:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                23:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
 zone:  ZONEA-MIGRATION
                20:13:00:11:0a:00:42:65
                20:13:00:11:0a:00:9d:c4
                20:14:00:11:0a:00:42:65
                20:14:00:11:0a:00:9d:c4
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:28
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:64
 zone:  phzprim_20310002ac02ffbh_00
                20:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20
 zone:  phzprim_20330002ac02ffbh_00
                20:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20
 zone:  phzprim_21310002ac02ffbh_00
                21:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20
 zone:  phzprim_21330002ac02ffbh_00
                21:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:18
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:1c
                10:00:i2:89:g9:c0:00:20


After configuring the new hosts to the storage:
I was supposed to use existing cfg Primera_FabricA. But instead I created another cfg as "cfg" shown in the below effective configuration:
Effective configuration:
cfg: cfg
 alias: a1_N0S3P1
                20:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a1_N0S3P3
                20:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a2_N1S3P1
                21:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a2_N1S3P3
                21:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a3_N2S3P1
                22:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a3_N2S3P3
                22:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: a3_N3S3P1
                23:31:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af
 alias: Primera_N3S3P3
                23:33:00:02:ac:02:ff:bh
                20:00:00:03:31:00:ff:af

I am not able to delete the above zoning configuration now. `enter preformatted text here`
```

Comment: Depending on the commands used, the old zone configuration may have been destroyed. If it's still defined but not active, then make it the active cfg. You cannot delete the active cfg. If you only have one cfg, then the only option is disabling zoning.

Comment: That's a fibre channel san. I doubt many NE users would even recognize it, even fewer know what to do. (I have a stack of FC switches; haven't been used in years.)

Comment: Cfgdisable will disable all the zones and configurations. This is in production. Will it have disruptive impact? Also, researched and found cfgdisable and cfgdelete will delete this effective configuration? I don't want any risks though

Comment: You've already created a disruption. (removed all zoning, everyone can see everything) Consult with your experienced SAN administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved. I enabled the previous configuration using cfgenable  . Then I deleted the zones and removed the cfg using the same steps as mentioned in my question.